# Get post save event in Odoo

Tags: events, odoo

I want to execute a function after some record is saved in the database (something like `Signals` in Django).

I have tried using [Odoo Connector](http://odoo-connector.com/) but with no success. `connector` module is not present in `openerp.addons` package by default and I could not find a good resource to understand how to install it.

How can I execute a function every time a new record is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself.

1. I manually copied `connector` module from [github](https://github.com/OCA/connector) to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons` (to make sure it's in my IDE's libraries' path).
2. Installed the connector from Settings -> Local Modules.
3. Used the following code (can be anywhere, even in `__init__.py` of your module)

   ```
   @on_record_create(model_names=['res.users', 'res.partner'])
   @on_record_write(model_names=['res.users', 'res.partner'])
   def delay_export(session, model_name, record_id, vals):
       """
       Do some real work here.
       """
       import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
   ```

The above code is based on [odoo-connector](http://odoo-connector.com/).